# how to change type of value char array to int in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, int

I'm new to CPP.

I'm trying to create small console app.

my qustion is, is there a way to change char array to integer...?!

for example:

`char myArray[]= "12345678"` to `int = 12345678` ...?!

tnx

Comment: atoi, sscanf, stringstream...

Comment: @yasouser the question is in C++, not C. Mat's comment is right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't "change" a type. What you want is to create an object of a certain type, using an object of the other type as input.

Since you are new to C++, you should know that using arrays for strings is not recommended. Use a real string:

```
std::string myString = "12345678";
```

Then you have two standard ways to convert the string, depending on which version of C++ you are using. For "old" C++, [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream):

```
std::istringstream converter(myString);
int number = 0;
converter >> number;
if (!converter) {
    // an error occurred, for example when the string was something like "abc" and
    // could thus not be interpreted as a number
}
```

In "new" C++ (C++11), you can use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

```
int number = std::stoi(myString);
```

With error handling:

```
try {
    int number = std::stoi(myString);
} catch (std::exception const &exc) {
    // an error occurred, for example when the string was something like "abc" and
    // could thus not be interpreted as a number
}
```

Comment: Thats a lot to understand for a guy new to C++

Comment: @yasouser: Yes, but what else should he do? He has to learn about strings anyway if he is currently hacking around with char arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Use `boost::lexical_cast`:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

char myArray[] = "12345678";
auto myInteger = boost::lexical_cast<int>(myArray);
```

Comment: For someone new to C++ you should probably point him on how to get Boost.

Comment: You Google “boost c++,” click the first result and click “Get Boost.”

Comment: @yasouser, do you consider being new to C++ being the same as being new to thinking, using the internet and computers?

Answer (score 0):

The `atoi` function does exactly this.

Comment: It has undefined behaviour for some inputs and no failure indication though.

Comment: @David: atoi cannot distinguish between "0" and "x".

Comment: For a very simple question, it's nice to give a very simple answer. Yes, we can go on about subtle nuances.

Comment: That's not a nuance. atoi() is a severely broken function, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from atoi() with C++11 standard compliant compiler you can use [std::stoi()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/).

Comment: atoi() should be avoided because of error handling. std::to_string() does the opposite of what he wants...

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Thanks for pointing out. I meant to point to stoi.